# What could cause a string of murders with no witnesses?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In my current game I had a slew of murders take place in my fortress. It was only after 4-5 murders did someone witness something and I was able to place him in custody. Is a serial killer personality part of the game? I have never seen anything like this before. Even more curious was how he refused water or food once imprisoned.

Comment: Was the dwarf actually a vampire?

Comment: @studoku not sure but I have seen a couple vampire dwarves in my fortress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the current version of the game (v0.34.11), I'm not aware of any [personality traits](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Personality_trait) or [attributes](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Attribute) that would cause a dwarf to commit several unprovoked murders in secret.

As mentioned in the comments by Studoku, a likely cause could be the presence of a [Vampire](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Vampire) in your fortress. A strong indication of this is if the corpses of victims are being discovered "drained of blood". This would tie in with your prisoner refusing food and water (their thirt will be… somewhat different).

Another possible cause for a string of unexplained deaths could be the presence of one or more [Ghosts](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Ghost) in the fortress. These are usually the result of deceased dwarves not being properly buried or memorialised.

Comment: They were all drained of blood so that makes sense, how can get rid of vampires?

Comment: @Paralytic You can find them, gather them in one place and wall them in. Or I think a career in military is perspective these days. On one hand, they kill your dorfs. On the other, they have really impressive skills, so think over whether you really want to get rid of them.

Comment: Also, if you wall them in, they make your Fortress more or less invincible (because they never die of old age, thirst or hunger - even if the rest of your Fort is wiped out, new migrants will show up eventually)

Comment: It's worth noting that the above isn't entirely true. If you have a massacre and only the vampires survive, ghosts will beat up and kill your vampires.

Comment: Yes, ghosts are still a risk. You'd have to let the vampires out of their isolation chamber to build memorial slabs, or until new migrants arrive.